# SSIS - Read Mulitple File .txt to SQL Using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, transform, readfile

I have a multiple Source Data.

[image]

I want to read the data using one SSIS Transform File. I using Foreach Loop Editor.

[image]

I can make the SSIS to read the data from that multiple file .txt above.
But, when the SSIS's run, that SSIS return one value form Report_S001 even path file that read of SSIS include Report_S002

[image]

I Think, it can make because the source file that selected only from Report_001

[image]

Any one can help me, so that the SSIS can transform file from two source file .txt with correct Data and with only one execute/run?

My string Connection

[image]

The expression
[image]

Connection string expression
[image]

Comment: Your images don't tell us enough about your set up, but I *assume* you haven't set the connection string for your flat file connection to be an expression.

Comment: @Larnu, that appears to be correct. The flat file connection is clearly visible on the screens as not parameterised.

Comment: *"The flat file connection is clearly visible on the screens"* not the bit that tells me if it's dynamic or not; it's always hidden behind a dialogue window.

Comment: So what expression have you used and on what setting? It's clearly not working

Comment: @Larnu I use variable VarSourceFile

Comment: For *what* setting...? The images dont tell me that the connection is dynamic, like I said, and just having a variable doesn't achieve anything if it's not used.

Comment: I am sorry @Larnu it is so difficult to explain. But I have follow this step http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-load-multiple-files-to-table-with.html

Comment: I *know* how to make a dynamic connection manager, @dodo . I'm asking you what *you* did... Again, *what* is the expression you used and what what setting to make the connection manager dynamic

Comment: @Larnu Can I discuss with you in teams or zoom?

Comment: @Larnu Please show me the image where i would manage the connection string

Comment: And that image proves me right. Connection String doesn't have an expression. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess here, as despite asking what has done to make the connection manager dynamic the OP won't share that information, and the images hide it.

As a result I assume that they haven't done so.

You simply need to edit your connect manager. in the properties pane, when the connection manager is selected, Locate `ConnectionString, and select <<expression>> in the drop down. Then set the expression to be the value of the variable that holds the File Path of the file to be loaded.

Comment: Please show me the image where i would manage the connection string

Comment: Visual Studio isn't available on ChromeOS or Linux, so I can't from home, @dodo , but like I said, it's in the Properties pane, which (I suspect) you have hidden behind the Output pane in your screenshots. Just hit `F4` to show it otherwise.